# Query without Union operator SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

```
TABLE X
 col1,col2
   1  , 2
   1  , 7
   1  , 4
   1  , 8
   2  , 3
   2  , 1
   2  , 2
   3  , 1
   3  , 8
   3  , 9
   3  , 4
   4  , 5
   4  , 3
   4  , 2
   4  , 8
   4  , 4
```

I want to retrieve the col1 values that contains in the col2 the values 2 and 4
in this case it will retrieve the values 1 and 4
How can i accomplish this without using the UNION ALL operator ?

The query that i am using is

```
select distinct col1
       from X as A
       where col1 = (
          select col1 from (
             select distinct col1
             from X as B
             where A.col1 = B.col1 and col2 = 2 
          union ALL
             select distinct col1
             from X as C
             where A.col1 = C.col1 and col2 = 4 
         ) D
       group by col1
       having count(col1) > 1
       )
```

It is returning the correct result but i guess is to performance expensive.
Can anyone give me ideas about how to achieve the same result but without unions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best performance will come from inner joining the table with itself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X1.col1
FROM X X1 INNER JOIN X X2 ON X1.col1=X2.col1
WHERE X1.col2=2 AND X2.col2=4
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is called [Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), here is one way to do so:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tablex
WHERE col2 IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) >=2
```

The `HAVING COUNT(col2) >=2` will ensure that the selected `col1` must have both the two values 2 and 4 at least.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c2e2/2)

Comment: Indeed, the demo you attached is correct - but the query there differs from the one you posted in your answer. The difference is in the `DISTINCT` within the `COUNT`.

Comment: @PaF - The query works fine also for the case you explained without the `DISTINCT` see [it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1aeeb/2)

Comment: duplicate entries is exactly the case I was talking about :)

Comment: @PaF - Aha, Thanks. OK Sorry for that